# Webbrowser не отображает HTML страницу

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

Webbrowser не отображает HTML страницу,в чем может быть причина ?
Использую метод NavigateToString
Как параметр передаю следующую строку

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
< html >
    < head >
        < meta http - equiv = 'Content-Type' content = 'text/html;charset=UTF-8' >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div dir=\"ltr\">
            <a href=\"mailto:niki@gmail.com\">Привет Мир</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </ body >
</ html >
```

Comment: Скажите, `< html > .. < /html >` и `<html> .. </html>` это два одинаковых тега?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ думаю да

Comment: @EvgeniyZ был весьма удивлен,что все настолько важно,спасибо)

Comment: Ну это синтаксис и от него не убежишь. Сам компонент WebBrowser довольно скудный и не умеет исправлять ошибки в коде. Так что каждая ошибка в HTML будет там ох как заметна...